# Have each loop iteration create a new line of data in a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I found and edited some code that records water flow data off of a flowmeter. I have managed to edit the script to run for only 5 mins and write to a file (I tried a .csv file but I am realizing this may not be entirely possible). However, when the script runs, the data file created just lists one "row" of recorded data. The while loop runs every 5 seconds for about 5 mins and provides a timestamp and a flow-rate reading, I'm trying to get the script to continuously record data. Here is the code:

```
import json
import time
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import csv
  
class FlowMeter():
    ''' Class representing the flow meter sensor which handles input pulses
        and calculates current flow rate (L/min) measurement
    '''
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.flow_rate = 0.0
        self.last_time = datetime.now()
  
    def pulseCallback(self, p):
        ''' Callback that is executed with each pulse 
            received from the sensor 
        '''
       
        # Calculate the time difference since last pulse recieved
        current_time = datetime.now()
        diff = (current_time - self.last_time).total_seconds()
       
        # Calculate current flow rate
        hertz = 1. / diff
        self.flow_rate = hertz / 7.5
       
        # Reset time of last pulse
        self.last_time = current_time
    
    def getFlowRate(self):
        ''' Return the current flow rate measurement. 
            If a pulse has not been received in more than one second, 
            assume that flow has stopped and set flow rate to 0.0
        '''
       
        if (datetime.now() - self.last_time).total_seconds() > 1:
            self.flow_rate = 0.0
        
        return self.flow_rate
  
def main():
    ''' Main function for repeatedly collecting flow rate measurements
        and sending them to the SORACOM API
    '''
   
    # Configure GPIO pins
    INPUT_PIN = 7
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
    GPIO.setup(INPUT_PIN, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
   
    # Init FlowMeter instance and pulse callback
    flow_meter = FlowMeter()
    GPIO.add_event_detect(INPUT_PIN,
                          GPIO.RISING,
                          callback=flow_meter.pulseCallback,
                          bouncetime=20)
    end_time = datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes=5)
    while True:
        timestamp = str(datetime.now())
        flow_rate = flow_meter.getFlowRate()
        time.sleep(5)
        print('Timestamp: %s' % timestamp)
        print('Flow rate: %f' % flow_rate)
        header = ['Time','Flow Rate']
        data = [timestamp, flow_rate]
        with open('flowrate.csv', 'w', encoding='UTF8', newline='') as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerow(header)
            writer.writerow(data)
        if datetime.now() > end_time:
            break 
if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

I've included my "data writing" strings near the bottom in the while loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opening the file with mode `'w'` overwrites the whole file every time.  So, just write the header at the beginning, and "append" later on:

```
def main()
    with open('flowrate.csv', 'w', encoding='UTF8', newline='') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(header)

    ... later, in the loop ...

        with open('flowrate.csv', 'a', encoding='UTF8', newline='') as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerow(data)
```

This is only practical if you're really only writing a row every now and then.  If you're writing more often, then you should just keep the file open and reuse the `writer` instance.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you're opening the file and effectively truncating (rewriting) it each time. Instead, open the file, then run the loop.

```
    with open('flowrate.csv', 'w', encoding='UTF8', newline='') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(header)
        while True:
            timestamp = str(datetime.now())
            flow_rate = flow_meter.getFlowRate()
            time.sleep(5)
            print('Timestamp: %s' % timestamp)
            print('Flow rate: %f' % flow_rate)
            header = ['Time','Flow Rate']
            data = [timestamp, flow_rate]
                writer.writerow(data)

            if datetime.now() > end_time:
                break
```